# printing 2 columns in a table while in for loop

Tags: php

I am trying to print results from a mysql query in a table that will be in 2 columns. to do this through my for loop i did the following:

```
    $num = 1;
            while($r = $qry->fetch())
            {
                    if (!fmod($num,2)) echo '<tr>';
                    echo "<td>" . $num . "</td>";
                    if (!fmod($num,2)) echo '</tr>';
                    $num++;
           }
```

however,  each row is getting its own row in the table.  even though $num is printed and shows 1,2,3,4 and so on.  what am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it almost right, but each iteration needs to EITHER display a `<tr>` OR an `</tr>` so:

https://eval.in/93455

```
$num = 1;
        while($num < 11)
        {
                if (fmod($num,2)) echo '<tr>';
                echo "<td>" . $num . "</td>";
                if (!fmod($num,2)) echo '</tr>';
                $num++;
       }
```

Note I altered your while condition for test purposes

Comment: This won't work, as the first fmod is checking if it is divisible by two, so it won't display the first time.  They are mismatched.  Look at my answer.

Comment: You can clearly see the working eval.in link that my syntax is correct and starts off with a `<tr>`, so I guess yours is backwards, eh? As far as your second comment, I already addressed that on the last line, as the DB loop is not germane to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you  do this instead. It creates a table, and lists column1 and column2 for each row.

```
    $result
        ?>
         <table>
          <tr>
           <th> Data for column 1</th>
          </tr>
         <tr>
        <?
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {

          echo "<td>".$row['dataforcolumn1']."</td>";
        }
    ?>
</tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: my sql result is 1 column, a list of items.  I dont want to print each item on its own row. it leaves a ton of extra space, i want to:  <tr><td>1st item</td><td>2nd item</td></tr>....etc....

Comment: This would be handy if you each row from the result is to be a row in the HTML, but I have a suspicion that each column in the HTML table corresponds to a row in the result.  Like displaying images from a gallery or something.

Comment: After I changed it to one column, it should create a new table data <td> for each result. Then after the while loop finishes, it caps that single row and closes the table.

Comment: That still would not work as it would just create tons of columns.  It looks like the intended use is for two columns per row.

Comment: Ah. There is the issue. I misunderstood. Thinking he wanted a ton of columns. +1 for pwning me

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify it with doing this:

```
$num = 1;
            while($r = $qry->fetch_array())
            {
                    if(fmod($num,2)) echo "</tr>\n";
                    echo "<td>" . $r['columnName'] . "</td>\n";
                    if(!fmod($num,2)) echo '</tr>';
                    $num++;
           }
```

Mainly, this is changing the **fmod** command to be divisible by 2 to end the  tag as you want it to add that after there are two  tags added (meaning it SHOULD be divisible by 2).

Comment: This is also using fetch_array instead, as I find it useful for my purposes.

Comment: givin the checkbox to digital because he beat you by a few seconds :)  thanks!